# using git rebase interactive mode with --rebase-merges properly

Tags: git, rebase, interactive

something doesn't work quite right for me with `git rebase -i --rebase-merges`
it goes like that.
I ha e my main branch, from my main branch i diverged to branch develop_xxx for the time we are in code freeze.
something like this :

```
main -> a' -> a ->b' -> b ->c' ->c 
                                  | develop_xxx-> aa' -> aa -> bb' -> bb
```

each letter with a ' is a merge commit while the regular letter is the commit that comes with it.
Now even though we are in code freeze we and to insert commits `d'->d` into main, and thus want to rebase develop_xxx, to keep comparability i wanted to keep the merge request as well.

Now what i did and the problem.
i did: from branch develop_xxx: `git rebase -i --rebase-merges origin main`
i over-viewed the interactive merge script with all it's resets and labels, looks legit, meaning a label before the pick, a label after the pick and then reset to the head state before the pick then merge with the label after the pick (so merge head before the commit with this commit). But the end result after the rebase is this:
`develop_xxx-> d' -> d -> aa' -> bb'-> aa ->  bb`

i must emphasize that the commit merges are correct meaning they point to the right two commits, but they appear one after the other instead of merge commit -> commit -> merge commit -> commit.
My finaly conclusion is that i'm doing something wrong, anyone got a hint ?

- BTW if i checkout a new branch from main with the latest commit and checkout new branch each time then cherry pick a single commit and ,erge it back, i am able to get the right structure of git that i wanted, with no chose i'll might do just that, but i can't understand why it can't be done automatically.